# eclipse works oddly

Tags: 11.04, upgrade, eclipse

I upgrade my ubuntu to 11.04 from 10.10.
After upgrade. Eclipse become odd.
The situation is that eclipse intermittently hang or become responseless.
I use sun-6-java jre and sdk.

Comment: Can you please check from System monitor if the JAVA processes dies after your close Eclipse?

Comment: Which version of eclipse you are using? Do you have any extra plugins installed? If you download an new clean bundle is it able to load?

Comment: I'm getting this too from time to time. It seems to be a bug rather than something we can fix on this question and answer platform.

Comment: Chakra-- the java process of eclipse does alive.

Comment: Chris-Top: I use Version: Helios Service Release 2. Plugins(jdt,platform sdk)

Comment: @taitung.bujn on replies user @ sign before the name you refer to, in order to get it in our inbox

Comment: @taitung.bujn Try loading eclipse from command line /home/chris/eclipse/eclipse and post the output. If you can avoid the failed assertions it would be quite clear I think the hang up error. Can you fill us with the details?

Comment: @taitung.bujn This seems to be a problem after upgrading to 11.04. The java processes created by Eclipse still persist after closing Eclipse and hog memory. I am killing them to recover memory but that is just a workaround

Comment: @Chakra That's not what's described in the question (and not what I'm seeing). What I get are hangs: the eclipse window becomes unresponsive (gray) and all I can do is forcing an exit.

Comment: @htorque It was something on sideline which I had observed and hence shared it :-), it by no means a solution to the problem. By the one trick which works for me when Eclipse window hangs is to Alt-Tab to some other application and then come back to Eclipse.

Comment: same to you, Chakra. However, that will let me be not focus on using eclipse to program.

Comment: Sorry for not reporting you the platform I installed eclipse. My notebook is Thinkpad T410 and 64bits. The same version of ubuntu 11.04 I run on my another notebook (ASUS F3JR 32bits) and eclipse is installed. However, no hang problem occurs on my laptop of ASUS.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Today I try again about the hang problem of eclipse.
well, the root cause shows up today.
When I close eclipse. An exception said that I do not have the permission 
to access a file--**nonChainingJarsCache**. 
This file is located at **/eclipse_project/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core**.
I check the file permission. I found that nonChainingJarsCache is set to root:root.
However, I chown the eclipse directory to common users after installing eclipse.
After all, this file at last is changed to root:root.
I don't know why it goes this way.

Then I go to check my ASUS laptop (ubuntu 11.04 with 32bits, helios).
I found that the permission of nonChainingJarsCache is not root:root. 
Instead, it's permission is common user.

Therefore, I sudo to execute the eclise. It works fine.
At last, I wrote a simple script to startup eclise.
and add this line (**gksudo -u root /opt/eclipse/eclipse**) to eclipse startup script.

Comment: Running ordinary software like an IDE as root is aways a veeeery bad ideia. Did you install it using repos or manual download? If manual, install it somewhere in your home folder, so permitions are not an issue. Or go for the repo version. Its not latest version, but its trouble-free.

Comment: Much better will be changing permission of given file. You can execute in terminal `sudo chown -R your_user_name  /eclipse_project`. It should change owner of all file to your user.